# How to trigger a function from one component to another component in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I'am creating React.js Weather project. Currently working on toggle switch which converts celcius to fahrenheit. The celcius count is created in one component whereas toggle button is created in another component. When the toggle button is clicked it must trigger the count and display it. It works fine when both are created in one component, but, I want to trigger the function from another component. How could I do it? Below is the code for reference

1. CelToFahr.js (Here the count is displayed)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CountUp from 'react-countup';

class CeltoFahr extends Component {
    state = {
        celOn: true
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {/* Code for celcius to farenheit */}
                <div className="weather">
            <div className="figures">
            <div className="figuresWrap2">
                <div className="mainFigureWrap">
                    <CountUp
                        start={!this.state.celOn ? this.props.temp.cel : this.props.temp.fahr}
                        end={this.state.celOn ? this.props.temp.cel : this.props.temp.fahr}
                        duration={2}
                        >
                        {({ countUpRef, start}) => (
                            <h1 ref={countUpRef}></h1>
                        )}
                    </CountUp>    
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                {/*End of Code for celcius to farenheit */}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default CeltoFahr
```

2. CelToFahrBtn (Here the toggle button is created)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CelToFahr from './CeltoFahr'

class CelToFahrBtn extends Component {
    state = {
        celOn: true
    }

    switchCel = () => {
        this.setState({ celOn: !this.state.celOn })
    }

    render = (props) => {
        return ( 
            <div className="button" style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
            <div className="weather">
            <div className="figures">
            <div className="figuresWrap2">
            <div className="mainFigureWrap">
                <div onClick={this.switchCel} className="CelSwitchWrap">
                    <div className={"CelSwitch" + (this.state.celOn ? "" : " transition")}>
                        <h3>C°</h3>
                        <h3>F°</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div> 
        )
    }
}

export default CelToFahrBtn
```

Here when I click on switchCel it must trigger the celcius to fahrenheit value and vice-versa. How to do it? Any suggestions highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would have the celToFahr be the parent component of the celToFahrBtn and then pass the function you want to invoke via props

```
<CellToFahrBtn callback={yourfunction}/>
```

What else could you do is having a common parent for these to components where you would again do the execution via props and callbacks

The 3rd option would be having a global state which would carry the function like Redux or Reacts own Context. There again you would get the desired function via props and you would execute it whenever you like. This is the best option if your components are completely separated in both the UI and in source hierarchically, but I don't think this is the case in this case.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

These are pretty much all the options you have

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you'd need to lift your state up and then pass the state and handlers to the needed components as props.

`CeltoFahr` & `CelToFahrBtn` would then become stateless components and would rely on the props that are passed down from TemperatureController

```js
class TemperatureController extends Component {
    state = {
        celOn: true
    }

    switchCel = () => {
        this.setState({ celOn: !this.state.celOn })
    }


    render () {
       return (
         <React.Fragment>
            <CeltoFahr celOn={this.state.celOn} switchCel={this.state.switchCel} />
            <CelToFahrBtn celOn={this.state.celOn} switchCel={this.state.switchCel}/>
         </React.Fragment>
       )
    }
}
```

It's probably better explained on the React Docs https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

See this more simplified example:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Display = ({}) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);


    return <div>
        <span>{count}</span>
        <Button countUp={() => setCount(count +1)}></Button>
    </div>
}

const Button = ({countUp}) => {
    return <button>Count up</button>
}
```

It's always possible, to just pass down functions from parent components.  See [Extracting Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#extracting-components) for more information.

It's also pretty well described in the "Thinking in React" guidline. Specifically [Part 4](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live) and [Part 5](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-5-add-inverse-data-flow).

Answer (score 0):

In React you should always try to keep components as dumb as possible. I always start with a functional component instead of a class component (read [here](https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108) why you should).

So therefore I'd turn the button into a function:

```
import React from 'react';
import CelToFahr from './CeltoFahr';

function CelToFahrBtn(props) {
  return (
    <div className="button" style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
      <div className="weather">
        <div className="figures">
          <div className="figuresWrap2">
            <div className="mainFigureWrap">
              <div onClick={() => props.switchCel()} className="CelSwitchWrap">
                <div
                  className={'CelSwitch' + (props.celOn ? '' : ' transition')}
                >
                  <h3>C°</h3>
                  <h3>F°</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CelToFahrBtn;
```

And you should put the logic in the parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CountUp from 'react-countup';
import CelToFahrBtn from './CelToFahrBtn';

class CeltoFahr extends Component {
  state = {
    celOn: true
  };

  switchCel = () => {
    this.setState({ celOn: !this.state.celOn });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="weather">
          <div className="figures">
            <div className="figuresWrap2">
              <div className="mainFigureWrap">
                <CelToFahrBtn switchCel={this.switchCel} celOn={celOn} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```